# How to show Image in full screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I’m trying to make simple meme app using Swift.I need to set up image at full screen.You can see [Main StoryBoard with constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHeEQ.png) here. But when im picking image that must fill full screen in portrait as result there is blank spaces in top and bottom. Similarly with landscape image but now spaces are on [right and left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKSJd.png). Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please try to inline the images, if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `UIImageView`'s contentMode to aspectFill.

Either in the storyboard…

[image]

or in code…

```
imageView.contentMode = .aspectFill
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement a very handy third party library, easy to use : https://github.com/JanGorman/Agrume

It enables you to handle every kind of gestures, interactions, zooms etc..  on your UIImageView.
Thus, you won't have to worry about portrait/landscape constraints.

@Ashley Mills answer is the answer, mine is just an advice.

Comment: Thanks ill check it